# MVC 3: how to update checkboxlist when dropdownlistitem is selected?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

for last two days i was trying to figure out how to update a checkboxlist dynamicly when a new item in dropdownlist is selected by help of javascript.

Ive done same thing for a week ago where i should do update to a from a dropdownlist to a dropdownlist.

What ive got so far :

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.User, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.UserList, "-- vælg bruger --")
    if (Model.checkboxlist != null)
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < Model.checkboxlist.Count; i++)
       {
        <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => Model.checkboxlist[i].check)
            @Html.LabelFor(c => Model.checkboxlist[i].Id, Model.checkboxlist[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(c => Model.checkboxlist[i].Id)

        </div>
       }
    }
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#User').change(function () {
    alert('HEJ!');
        var selectedUser = $(this).val();
        alert(selectedUser);
        if (selectedUser != null && selectedUser != '-- vælg bruger --' && selectedUser != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("getPdfCheckBoxList","Admin")', { username: selectedUser },
            function (employee) {

                var checkboxlist = $('#checkboxlist');
                checkboxlist.empty();

                $.each(employee, function (index, employee) {
                    checkboxlist.append($('<checkbox/>', {
                        checked = 'false'
                    }));
                });
            });

        }
    });
</script>
```

when i am loading view Model.checkboxlist is null cause i dont return anything to model apart of dropdownlist items.

ControllerAction :

```
public ActionResult getPdfCheckBoxList(String username)
{
    MethodService service = new MethodService();
    var list = new List<PDFCheckBoxList>();


    foreach (var pdfCheckBoxList in getPDFFileNames(username))
    {
        list.Add(new PDFCheckBoxList { check = false, Id = pdfCheckBoxList });
    }
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Right now even Alert("HEJ") doesnt even get fired, and i simply cant figure out why... Help please?

Comment: any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: okay 1 problem solved... instead of checked = 'false' there should be checked: 'false'... so now i am  getting pop ups... but still list checkboxlist inst getting updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use partial views and have your controller action return a partial and build the markup on the server instead of doing it on the client:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.User, 
        Model.UserList, 
        "-- vælg bruger --",
        data_url = Url.Action("getPdfCheckBoxList", "Admin")
    )
    <div id="checkboxlist">
        @if (Model.checkboxlist != null)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_checkboxlist", Model.checkboxlist)
        }
    </div>
}
```

and then define `_checkboxlist.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<PDFCheckBoxList>
@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "checkboxlist";
}
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and finally the editor template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PDFCheckBoxList.cshtml` which will be rendered for each element:

```
@model PDFCheckBoxList
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.check)
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Id, Model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Id)
</div>
```

Now you could modify your javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Now that we no longer have any server side 
    // code here we could externalize this script
    // into a separate javascript file

    $('#User').change(function () {
        if (selectedUser != null && selectedUser != '') {
            var selectedUser = $(this).val();
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            var data = { username: selectedUser };
            $('#checkboxlist').load(url, data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

and finally your `getPdfCheckBoxList` action:

```
public ActionResult getPdfCheckBoxList(String username)
{
    var service = new MethodService();
    var list = getPDFFileNames(username)
        .Select(x => new PDFCheckBoxList 
        { 
            check = false, 
            Id = x 
        })
        .ToList();
    return PartialView("_checkboxlist", list);
}
```

If you want to build the markup on the client and have the controller action return JSON I would recommend you using some javascript templating framework.

Comment: i have 2 questions , why did you use partial then use editor template , why not the editor template from the get go ? and does `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` do ?

Comment: Answer to the first question: because the editor template is strongly typed to `PDFCheckBoxList` whereas the `getPdfCheckBoxList`  action passes an `IEnumerable<PDFCheckBoxList>` to the view. `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` allows to prefix all input field names generated by the HTML helpers. This is necessary so that we get `<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[0].check" />` instead of `<input type="checkbox" name="check" />` which would break the model binder conventions when you submit the form and attempt to map the values to the view model in the POST controller action.

Answer (score 0):

you either have the selector wrong `"#User"` , or that id is used multiple times on the same page

view generated page source from the browser and find if the `<select>` element has `id="User"` or there is multiple ids equal to `"User"`

Comment: Id and Name of select is User

Comment: okay 1 problem solved... instead of checked = 'false' there should be checked: 'false'... so now i am  getting pop ups... but still list checkboxlist inst getting updated

Comment: i really don't get your code , your emptying the checkbox list then appending new ones that are empty and don't have a name because of that the server cant read them , what do you want exactly ?

Comment: What i want is : on new item selection in dropdownlist, to show checkbox items corresponding to return value of getPdfCheckBoxList method. so its gonna be like cascading dropdownlists but with dropdownlist and checkboxes

Comment: does it return the correct value from the url ? check a tool like firebug in the console window when you select an item , check if it fires the ajax request or not , if it fires check the return value is correct or not

Comment: username returned to method is correct, return value of method is correct... its javascript part which updates checkboxlist is messed up